# How to set destination view controller using indexpath value?

Tags: objective-c, segue, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

I have a collection view controller if the user select any cell means its need to go destination view controller.

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        cell=[collectionview cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexNumberStorager];
        NSInteger indexnum;
        indexnum=indexNumberStorager.row;
        switch (indexnum) {
            case 1:
                if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Car"])
                {
                    CarCleaningVC *dest = [segue destinationViewController];


                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

i tried using this code but not working properly please help me to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`sender` here is the cell that has been selected by the user (if the segue is on cell selection). You don't need to store `indexPath` anywhere.

Simply typecast `sender` into `UICollectionViewCell`(or your subclass if you're using any), and call `indexPathForCell:` on your collection view to get the `indexPath`.

Sample code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSUInteger indexNum = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:(UICollectionViewCell*)sender].row;

    switch (indexNum)
    // Relevant code
}
```

Also, instead of depending on the segue `identifier`, try to use the `destinationViewController`'s class:

```
if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[CarCleaningVC class]]) {
    //relevant code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-
in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, set the cell tag. Something like-

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.tag=indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}
```

And then when you cast your sender to a cell, you can just access its tag which is your Collection View's Indexpath.row.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{
     UICollectionViewCell *cell=(UICollectionViewCell*)sender;
     NSInteger indexnum;
     indexnum=cell.tag;
    switch (indexnum) {
        case 1:
            if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Car"])
            {
                CarCleaningVC *dest = [segue destinationViewController];


            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```